# what does this line of code in express.js mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

Can someone explain in depth what does this line of code mean in NodeJS:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
```

Comment: It'd help a lot if you could elaborate on the way in which that statement seems confusing or mysterious. It's an extremely simple statement.

Comment: @Pointy thats true. I need to understand every single step and word of that statement. what exactly is happening not just blindly use it. Praveen could nearly answer me. ill followup on his answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
express.createServer();
```

The above line has the instance of `express` and creates a server instance (server handle) and returns the whole export class.

With the above, you are setting both `module.exports` as well as `app` to do further.

Comment: So first i am creating an instance of server, then export it, then use it as a variable 'app' correct?

Comment: @DragonKnight You can think of it like a chain of assignments. First we evaluate `express.createServer()` which evaluates to an instance of an express server (which is just some value in JavaScript), then `module.exports` is assigned that value. So now that `module.exports` has that value, we then assign `var app` to `module.exports` which is assigned to `express.createServer()` etc, so it creates a chain of assignments

Comment: @NickZuber thanks for answer. what happens if I later on write something like `module.exports = express.someOtherMethod()` ? am I overriding it or calling a new method of `module.exports`?

Comment: @DragonKnight You are overriding / setting the value mate. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten as:

```
module.exports = express.createServer();
var app = module.exports;
```